# Best way to capture effect of making people upset?

Tags: economics

I am an undergrad, I am planning to do some research to see how much I enjoy it before I apply for graduate programs.

I am researching the effects of a certain characteristic of a presenter making people upset, uncomfortable, aggravated or displeased during a short clip like a TV commercial.  My plan is to have subjects watch a short clip with a presenter and see if they are they aggravated, upset, uncomfortable with the presenter based on that one characteristic changing and compare this across demographics.  I do not have much experience with setting up and performing experiments.

How do I quantify how upset, uncomfortable, aggravated, or displeased the subject felt?

How do I make sure that every subjects experience is the same except for that one factor?

Do I have to do anything special because I will not be able to run the same test on the same exact subject?